# Calculate FPS with sfml

Tags: c++, sfml, frame-rate

This question is NOT related to the main loop in sfml. How do I calculate the actual framerate (for example, I have vsync enabled, but the main loop still runs at a high speed), so that it actually displays how fast the screen is updated (not the speed of the main loop). Measuring main loop speed is not important for me, but the actual window update speed is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFML did not provide a way to retrieve your current framerate, neither backends like OpenGL does. Therefore, the only way is to monitor the main loop speed, as you suggested.

Also, `window.setFrameLimit(60)` or `window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true)` or internal loop `sleep` on a 60Hz monitor causes the same effect in my SFML application, with the difference of V-Sync being more CPU and GPU expensive (due to their synchronization ways).
Therefore you can rely on calculating FPS by using `chrono` for example in your main loop.

Make sure to wrap your `draw` calls by using `time_point`(s), into `start` and `end` points and calculating time elapsed with `std::chrono::time_duration`.

Example:

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start;
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end;
float fps;
while(window.isOpen()){
    // Perform some non-rendering logic there...

    // Performed. Now perform GPU stuff...
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    // window.draw, etc.
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

     fps = (float)1e9/(float)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-start).count());
}
```

Comment: does sdl have a method for calculating fps (refresh rate)?

Comment: From this source (http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Average_FPS_Measurement) it seems that to calculate FPS, SDL does a similar approach than the one I have used by calling SDL_GetTicks. I think the accuracy level and the purpose is the same.